# Post carregados com ajax em wordpress repetidos

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Possuo uma página de post no meu site, nela são mostrados todos os post criados no wordpress, porém são muitos post, então coloquei uma aplicação que mostra apenas 5 post na página, e ao clicar no botão criado, são puxados mais 5 post, entretanto, alguns post vem repetidos. Gostaria de saber porque os post estão vindo repetidos.

Functions.php

```
<?php 

    add_action('wp_ajax_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_posts_by_ajax', 'load_posts_by_ajax_callback');

    function load_posts_by_ajax_callback() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts', 'security');
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'post', 
        'status'        => 'published', 
        'cat' => 3,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => '2',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) :
        ?>
        <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
           <div class="col-md-12 glossario">
              <h2 class="tituloGlossario"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color:#fff;"><p class="textoGlossario"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '...' ); ?></p></a>
          </div>
        <?php endwhile ?>
        <?php
    endif;

    wp_die();
    }
?>
```

Página de post:

```
<?php 
              $args = array(
                  'post_type'     => 'post', 
                  'status'        => 'published', 
                  'cat' => 3,
                  'order' => 'ASC',
                  'posts_per_page' => '2',
                  'paged' => 1,
              );
              $my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
              if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : 
              ?>
                  <div class="my-posts">
                      <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>
                          <div class="col-md-12 glossario">
                          <h2 class="tituloGlossario"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color:#fff;"><p class="textoGlossario"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '...' ); ?></p></a>
                      </div>
                      <?php endwhile ?>
                  </div>
              <?php endif ?>
              <div class="loadmore">Load More...</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
            var page = 2;
            jQuery(function($) {
                $('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
                    var data = {
                        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
                        'page': page,
                        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
                    };

                    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        $('.my-posts').append(response);
                        page++;
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Grato pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Voce precisa passar o `offset` nos argumentos para poder pegar os posts a partir da quantidade que você já carregou.

Inicialmente você vai passar o valor 0, e cada vez que você buscar os posts, você terá que passar um valor ao offset que é a quantidade de posts que você já tem carregado.

function.php

```
$paged = $_POST['page'];
$postsLength = ($_POST['postsLength'] > 0) ? $_POST['postsLength'] : 0;
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'post', 
    'status'        => 'published', 
    'cat' => 3,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '2',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'offset' => $postsLength
);
```

Script:

```
<script>
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
            var page = 2;
            var postsLength = 0;
            jQuery(function($) {
                $('body').on('click', '.loadmore', function() {
                    var data = {
                        'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
                        'page': page,
                        'postsLength': postsLength,
                        'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
                    };

                    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        $('.my-posts').append(response);
                        postsLength += response.length;
                        page++;
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Você pode ver sobre offset aqui na documentação: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Não sei como você ta chamando essa função exatamente, mas a idea é você armazenar sempre a quantidade de posts a cada requisição. Espero poder ter ajudado valeu!